# Remove filter from ROW LABELS on pivot table Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

How can I, or is it even possible to remove the access to a filter on the **Row Labels** on a pivot table, see image for REF.

Or even just hide it from View

[image]

My pivot tablse set up only has Row Labels and Values

( Note. Games Won and Win Ratio is outside of the PIVOT )

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right clicking on your pivot table > Pivot Table Options > Display > then uncheck the "Display field captions and filter drop downs" tick box

That should work.

Comment: Hiding in plain sight all along, only draw back is I cannot type in the cell, but i can live with that